# SQL multiple merge statements with same data source (WITH as)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to have multiple merge statements (one after another) in same query
but i can't use same date source. Example:

```
WITH DATA as(
SELECT * FROM tables_or_joins
            )

MERGE table_name as Target
USING
(SELECT * FROM DATA JOIN another table
)
....
do something more; --and finish this statement here

-- start another merge here
MERGE table_name_2 as Target
USING(
SELECT * FROM DATA and join with another table
)
do something else
```

But output is `Invalid object name 'DATA'.` In second merge. Is any other way how to use data in both merge? Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: If you need the same `DATA` for two statements, use a temporary table or table variable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is a better way (performance) to use temp table or declare DATA in each merge separately?

Comment: I'm using `@temp_table` for now and it works. thanks @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Actually a temporary table is probably *better* from a performance perspective, if the CTE is a complex query.  SQL Server does not materialize CTEs, so it would run the CTE code each time it is in a query.

Comment: My understanding is that the CTE code only runs once.  That's the rationale for using the keyword `with` as opposed to simply joining to a subquery.

Comment: @DanBracuk Your understanding is wrong

Answer (score 0):

CTE is only good for one statement

Cannot even do two simple selects on `DATA`

You can have multiple CTE but still only one actual statement

Answer (score -1):

You can use mutiple CTE statements

> WITH DATA as( SELECT * FROM tables_or_joins
>               ),  DATA2 AS( (SELECT * FROM DATA JOIN another table )
>
> SELECT * from DATA d join DATA2 d2 on d.id=d2.id
>
> OR
>
> Select * from DATA union  Select * from DATA2